# wss connection to php wrong frame format

Tags: php, ssl, websocket, wss

I'm doing a wss request from js to my PHP server and the handshake works good, but the response data frame has the first bytes as C7 instead of 81 so I can't decode the data.

I'm using a trusted SSL certificate.

My PHP code is:

Creation of websoket server:

```
$context = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'local_cert', '../../engine/fscert.pem');
stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'local_pk', '../../engine/fskey.key');
stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'allow_self_signed', true);
stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'verify_peer', false);
$errno, $errstr,STREAM_SERVER_BIND|STREAM_SERVER_LISTEN, $context);
$socket = stream_socket_server("tls://my-server.com:9444", $errno, $errstr,STREAM_SERVER_BIND|STREAM_SERVER_LISTEN, $context);
```

Handshake function:

```
$SecWebSocketAccept = base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($info['Sec-WebSocket-Key'] . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')));
    $upgrade = "HTTPS/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n" .
        "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" .
        "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
        "Sec-WebSocket-Accept:$SecWebSocketAccept\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($connect, $upgrade);
```

Where am I going wrong?